# AWS Lambda Discord Slash Command - Get data from sent message

Tags: aws-lambda, discord, discord.py

When a message is sent from Discord using the slash command, I can also send text along with the command. My issue is that when I pull the body of the message event in AWS Lambda, I don't see the message I sent with it. So if I send /getInfo "Simon" I want to be able to send stats stored on a DB for the character Simon.

When I try to get the JSON body, it doesn't have any information on the message text that was sent with the slash command. All I see is who sent it, what the command was, channel_id, etc.

Do you know if I can get the message text info when a slash command is sent? I didn't see anything in the Discord Developer docs on this.

Comment: How did you define your slash command? It looks like Discord requires you to define options (`ApplicationCommandOption`) to receive arguments after the command

Comment: Thank you! You are correct. I needed to add an option with type 3 (for text) and now the message text has been passed through to the JSON body.

json = {
    "name": "testEatMessage",
    "description": "Eat the message added to slash command",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "description": "The person's name",
            "type": 3,
            "required": True
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

When [registering a slash command](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#registering-a-command) with Discord, you need to specify what options are available for the command, otherwise they won't be passed to you.

You do that as part of the options block

```json
{
    "name": "mycommand",
    "description": "My command does my thing",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "myoption",
            "description": "My option",
            "type": 3,
            "required": True
        }
    ]
}
```

Once you do that, the argument that the user passed on the command will be available under `data`

```json
{
    // ...
    "data": { 
        "options": [{
            "name": "myoption",
            "value": "User value"
        }],
        // ...
    },
}
```